# Summon a mob on play at certain level

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

I have a Redstone timer to activate a command block. I've tried `summon vindicator @p[l>9]` but it doesn't work. I want to summon a vindicator at the player that's level 10 or higher within a 500 block radius but I have no idea how to do this. This is on Bedrock Edition.

Answer (score 0):

I am Bedrock as well.
Are you creating an arena? Get the coords on the other side from where you are. For example, if you created a 15-block arena, and you're on, let's say... `13 64 0`, you would spawn the Vindicator at the other side, `-13 64 0`. Use either one of these.
`/execute @p[scores:{level = 10}] ~~~ summon vindicator -13 64 0`

`/testfor @p[x=0,y=64,z=0,r=20,scores;{level = 10}]` with a redstone comparator on any direction, a redstone repeater and a normal command block that says `/summon vindicator -13 64 0`. I hope you find this helpful.